# Insert a row after each row in sql

Tags: sql, sql-update, row, sql-insert

I have a table which have 51 records, I want to insert a row after each row which will have all columns blank except 3 columns, Is there a specific syntax for that or how can I do it?

Comment: SQL rows have no order unless you're asking the database to order the result of a specific query for you. In other words, you can't really insert a row after each existing row, since "after each row" depends on the order of the rows in the query you're executing.

Comment: I smell some larger requirement, and a better description of the problem would help us help you.  Are you looking for a ResultSet with three empty rows after each row in a query?

Answer (score 1):

There are probably much better ways to do this, but...

If you're working with a SELECT statement and you want to return some columns null on every other row, you could do something like this(in MySQL):

```
SET @row_number:=0;
SET @row_number2:=0;

SELECT name
    ,selectname
    ,description
FROM(
SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number
    ,name
    ,selectname
    ,description
FROM plugin_mp_ninite_applications

UNION ALL

SELECT @row_number2:=@row_number2+1 AS row_number
    ,name 
    ,null
    ,null
FROM plugin_mp_ninite_applications
ORDER BY row_number, selectname
) x
```

[image: nullrows]

Obviously, this would be better done in the design tool of your report/dashboard/etc.